# Using Switch statement in another switch in C

Tags: c, switch-statement

So I'm trying to make a program mostly out of curiosity and little bit for my studies! But I came across this problem. When I try to use a switch statement in another one my program goes to default if I choose the case which the switch statement is in.

```
printf("Please enter the first character of the thing you want to get perimeter and area of off: ");
scanf_s("%c", &holder);

switch (toupper(holder))
{
case 'C':
    printf("Please enter the radius of the circle: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &a);
    if (a <= 0)
        printf("Please enter a positive radius!\n");
    else
    {
        perimeter = 2 * PI * a;
        area = PI * a * a;

        printf("Perimeter of the circle is %.2f\n", perimeter);
        printf("Area of the circle is %.2f\n", area);
    }
    break;
case 'R':
    printf("Please enter the two sides of the rectangle!\n");
    scanf_s("%d %d", &a, &b);

    if (a <= 0 || b <= 0)
        printf("Please enter positive numbers as sides values!\n");
    else
    {
        perimeter = a + a + b + b;
        area = a * b;

        printf("Perimeter of the rectangle is %.2f", perimeter);
        printf("Area of the rectangle is %.2f", area);
    }
    break;
case 'T':
    printf("Please enter a for calculation using 3 sides and b for 2 sides and the angle between them!");
    scanf_s("%c", &e);

    switch (e)
    {
    case 'a':
        printf("Please enter the three sides values!\n");
        scanf_s("%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c);

        if (a <= 0 || b <= 0 || c <= 0 || a >= b + c || b >= a + c || c >= a + b || a < abs(b - c) || b < abs(a - c) || c < abs(a - b))
            printf("Please enter viable side values!\n");
        else
        {
            perimeter = a + b + c;
            d = perimeter / 2;
            area = sqrt(d * (d - a) * (d - b) * (d - c));

            printf("Triangles perimeter is %2.f\n", perimeter);
            printf("Triangles area is %2.f\n", area);
        }
        break;
    case 'b':
        printf("Please enter 2 sides and the degree between them!\n");
        scanf_s("%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c);

        c1 = PI / 180 * c;
        perimeter = (a * a) + (b * b) - (2 * a * b * cos(c1));
        area = (1 / 2) * a * b * sin(c1);

        printf("Triangles perimeter is %2.f\n", perimeter);
        printf("Triangles area is %2.f\n", area);
        break;
    }
default:
    printf("Unknown character!\n");



}

system("pause");
```

}

Comment: What is your input? Give your full code.

Comment: Also share the input for which this is happening..

Comment: Does it completely skip the inner `switch` block or does it _also_ go to the default one? If this is the case, you are experiencing [fall through](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement#Fallthrough). You don't have a `break` statement after your inner `switch`.

Comment: This looks more like a `scanf` problam than a `switch` problem. (Your code is missing the `break` for `case 'T'` in the outer `switch`, so that execution falls through to the `default` case of the outer `switch`. The error message may be appropriate for both switches, though.)

Comment: No aparrent debuggin, DCV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first scanf input you must have given was say `T\n` (because you gave T followed by the enter key - which is `\n` on linux - assuming it's linux)

So it's not one but two characters in the stdin buffer currently. Hence,  when you scan the character `'e'` it actually reads `'\n'` instead of what the user enters next and hence goes into the default case in the inner switch.

**EDIT:** Since there is no default case in your inner switch and hence the case of `\n` is not handled anywhere. This also means no `break` was executed for the outer switch and hence all subsequent cases including default will be executed, that's why you get `Unknown Character`

So, if you are sure there will always be a press of the enter key you can do a `getchar()` before taking the second character.

```
getchar(); //removes \n from stdin
scanf_s("%c", &e);
```

Comment: First input: t Second input: a and Program displays "Unknown character" instead of executing case a.

Comment: @KubilayDoğru Put `break` after cast `T` . in that case both default and the case T are executed .